# Creating a grade variable in C#

Tags: c#

I am in this programming class, and one of the sections in this assignment I am trying to complete I keep getting stuck on. The instructions are to use a grade variable to determine a student's letter grade, but I seem to be missing something every time I run it. Would anyone be able to guide me in the right direction? I have submitted what I have so far.

```
public static char Test3(double grade)
    {
        char X = '?';
        if (X >= 90 && X <= 100)
        {
            X = 'A';
        }
        else if (X >= 80 && X < 90)
        {
            X = 'B';
        }
        else if (X >= 73 && X < 80)
        {
            X = 'C';
        }
        else if (X >= 70 && X < 73)
        {
            X = 'D';
        }
        else if (X >= 0 && X < 70)
        {
            X = 'F';
        }
        else if (X < 0 || X > 100)
        {
            X = '?';
        }

        return X;
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: *"but I seem to be missing something every time I run it"* - Can you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: Red flag: you never use the parameter `grade`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need some more information so we can help you. First of all, [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that we can copy/paste and run ourselves. Second describe what happens when you run your program. Do you get errors? If so, show the entire error. If not, show the output. Then describe what you want it to do instead.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: You initially assign `X` to `'?'` unconditionally and then you test that in all your `if`s. The numeric value of the `?` character is 63, so by your grading scale, it'll always be an F.

Comment: Delete the line "char X = '?'; and sync up the grade parameter with the X variable.  That means, either rename your parameter to X or rename the X in every if statement to grade.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking `X` variable in your `if`s you need to check `grade`.